# How to maximize grid dimensions given the number of elements

Tags: python, maximize

I have `n` elements as a input and a function `make_grid(n)` which will calculate the dimensions of a grid that will contain the elements. Let's suppose that `n = 12`, then the function must calculate that the width is 4 and the height is 3 and not 1 and 12 or so.  Similarly, `n = 24` should return 6 and 4.

I tried to use `ceil(sqrt(n))` to get one dimension, but is not a general case at all, and playing with cases (n even, `sqrt(n) == ceil(sqrt(n))`) hasn't worked.

Edit:
[Finding the optimum column and row size for a table with n elements and a given range for its proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291326/finding-the-optimum-column-and-row-size-for-a-table-with-n-elements-and-a-given/3291463#comment24402181_3291463)
I already see this question but the coding throws me for n = 24 dimensions 5 and 5.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is as follows:

Take the integer `n` as the input of the function. The goal is to obtain the "squarest" table. As @John suggested we must calculate `sqrt(n)` to get an idea of the dimensions. On the other hand we must calculate all the divisors of `n` in order to do choose the nearest divisors to `sqrt(n)`.

How do we choose the nearest low value? we can use this tip (Python): [Finding index of an item closest to the value in a list that's not entirely sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706041/finding-index-of-an-item-closest-to-the-value-in-a-list-thats-not-entirely-sort) and get the index of the nearest value in the list of divisors, let's say `hIndex`.
Then the other dimension can be calculated dividing `n` by `divisors[hIndex]` or using a new index `wIndex = hIndex + 1` and get `divisors[wIndex]`.

The Python code is this (note that I used al lazy evaluation to find the divisors):

```
import numbers
from math import sqrt

def get_dimensions(n):
    tempSqrt = sqrt(n)
    divisors = []
    currentDiv = 1
    for currentDiv in range(n):
        if n % float(currentDiv + 1) == 0:
         divisors.append(currentDiv+1)
    #print divisors this is to ensure that we're choosing well
    hIndex = min(range(len(divisors)), key=lambda i: abs(divisors[i]-sqrt(n)))
    
    if divisors[hIndex]*divisors[hIndex] == n:
        return divisors[hIndex], divisors[hIndex]
    else:
        wIndex = hIndex + 1
        return divisors[hIndex], divisors[wIndex]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for numbers that divide `n` evenly, so you'll need to compute the factors of `n`, and take the two that are closest to `sqrt(n)`.  One will be the largest factor less than or equal to `sqrt(n)` (call this `f`) and the other will be `n/f`.

However, you'll get strange-looking grids for many numbers, like 74, or any prime number.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. The cases where are numbers which factors are far between them the table will be too long or tall. I will use numbers that stay in some screen-like ratio, so that's not a problem. However I will think in the factors and `srqt(n)` idea.

Comment: Let's say n = 50, and floor(qrt(50)) = 7, but 7 is not a factor D:

Comment: You're right.  It's not.  That wasn't what I was suggesting, though.  The factors of 50 are 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, and 50.  So the two closest factors to `sqrt(50)` are 5 and 10, giving you a 5 x 10 or a 10 x 5 grid.

Comment: OK I see your point, I have to read well an answer before ask anything. Thanks for your patience, I got the idea of your solution.

Comment: I don't know if is well said in english but what I am really looking at are not the "factors" of `n`, I'm looking at the divisors of `n`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for integer factorization algorithms.

Check here: [Efficiently finding all divisors of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793009/efficiently-finding-all-divisors-of-a-number)

And here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms

Then just choose a pair of factors that best matches your goals.