# Calculate maximum available rows and columns to fill with N amount of items

Tags: javascript, factorization

By reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377512/393406) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3291372/393406), I've come up with a function, that's probably more complex than it should be, but, man, my math sux:

```
function tablize(elements)
{
    var root = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(elements));

    var factors = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= root; i++)
    {
        if (elements % i === 0)
        {
            factors.push([i, elements / i]);
        }
    }

    var smallest = null;

    for (var f = 0; f < factors.length; f++)
    {
        var factor = factors[f];

        var current = Math.abs(factor[0] - factor[1]);

        if (!smallest || factors[smallest] > factor)
        {
            smallest = f;
        }
    }

    return factors[smallest];
}
```

While this does work, it provides results I'm not satisfied with.

For instance - 7, it's divided in 1x7, where I'd like it to be 3x3. That's the minimum, optimal, grid size needed to fill with 7 elements.

Also - 3, it's divided in 1x3, where I'd like it to be 2x2.

I need this for a live camera feed frame distribution on a monitor, but I'm totally lost. The only way I can think of is building an extra function to feed with previously generated number and divide again, but that seems wrong.

What is the optimal solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For squares:

```
function squareNeeded(num) {
    return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(num));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aKNVq/

(I think you mean the smallest square of a whole number that is bigger than the given amount, because if you meant a rectangle, then your example for seven would be 2*4 instead of 3*3.)